# How can I use MariaDB (XAMPP) in Windows?

Tags: windows, xampp, mariadb

I am new using XAMPP. I have installed it and everything works fine, but I don´t know how can I manage MariaDB engine to create and set new DDBB. My goal is to create a website in localhost and use MariaDB to develop a "Sign in" system for the users.

Every tip is welcome. Thanks!

Comment: This question is very broad, and not really suitable for Stack Overflow as it stands. I'd suggest reading  [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then coming back and editing your question to apply some of the advice there. Your best first stop will probably be to look online for some tutorials that get you started.

Comment: What is "DDBB"?  A search points me at the Urban dictionary, but suspect their definition would not apply?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends on what you mean by 'using mariadb on windows'. If it's starting mariadb, then navigate to \xampp\mysql\bin and start mariadb i.e.

```
cd \xampp\mysql\bin
mysql -u root -p
```

If you want to create a website using with mariadb backend, make sure you save your work in the htdocs folder inside the xampp folder